# Is it possible to install llvmlite Python package on Cygwin?

Tags: python, windows-7, llvm, cygwin

When trying to install `llvmlite` Python package on cygwin, I get the following errors:

```
$ pip install llvmlite
Downloading/unpacking llvmlite
  Downloading llvmlite-0.4.0.tar.gz (69kB): 69kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/setup.py) egg_info for package llvmlite

Installing collected packages: llvmlite
  Running setup.py install for llvmlite
    got version from file /cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.4.0', 'full': '8a681a2726ae79b640b4147b13cdd5e309a5c74f'}
    /usr/bin/python2.7 /cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 112, in <module>
        main()
      File "/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 108, in main
        raise RuntimeError("unsupported platform: %r" % (sys.platform,))
    RuntimeError: unsupported platform: 'cygwin'
    error: command '/usr/bin/python2.7' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-Skcu4R-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

got version from file /cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.4.0', 'full': '8a681a2726ae79b640b4147b13cdd5e309a5c74f'}

running build_ext

/usr/bin/python2.7 /cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/ffi/build.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 112, in <module>

    main()

  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 108, in main

    raise RuntimeError("unsupported platform: %r" % (sys.platform,))

RuntimeError: unsupported platform: 'cygwin'

error: command '/usr/bin/python2.7' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-Skcu4R-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip_build_Administrator/llvmlite
Storing debug log for failure in /home/Administrator/.pip/pip.log
```

### Has anyone succeeded in installing llvm on Cygwin? How can I fix my errors?

I'm using Cygwin 1.7.35(0.287/5/3), Python 2.7.8, and Windows 7.